# ClassDefNoFound even though the jar that I'm dependent on is in my jar

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm writing a LabyMod addon to create a shop bot for minecraft clients.

I've well succeeded to do so, at least in my dev-environement in eclipse. Now I wanted to publish it, and to do this, LabyMod provides a possibility to use gradle for wrapping up all stuff that is relevant to the addon in the addon jar, that can then simply be dragged into the "addons"-Folder.

However, when I do this, the plugin didn't appear in the plugin overview, and I found out that there was an error when loading the plugin (Class def not found). I use okhttp3 to send some web requests to my verification server, so I just added it in eclipse as dependent jar, but they were not included when gradle built the jar. So I wasn't very surprised with that, and looked for a possibility to add my dependencies to the jar directly.

I found out in the commments of the predefined `build.gradle` to simply put all files in a predefined "libs"-folder which seemed to be fine. Here's the issue: Although the jars definitely are a part of the jar, the classdefnotfound-thing still happenes. Here's what I mean.

JD-GUI says of my jar:
[image: Contents of the jar]

So, the jars definitely are there, and jd-gui can find them in the code as well, since you can click on the imports and get taken to the place where okhttp3 defined the imported class.

Here's however the error that I get, when trying to load the addon:

```
catching
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder
    at borg.locutus.grieferbot.utils.NetworkUtilities.sendGet(NetworkUtilities.java:70)
    at borg.locutus.grieferbot.utils.NetworkUtilities.getPermissionLevelOfPlayer(NetworkUtilities.java:51)
    at borg.locutus.grieferbot.GrieferBOTAddon.initPermissionLevel(GrieferBOTAddon.java:50)
    at borg.locutus.grieferbot.GrieferBOTAddon.onEnable(GrieferBOTAddon.java:43)
    at net.labymod.addon.AddonLoader.enableAddon(AddonLoader.java:349)
    at net.labymod.addon.AddonLoader.enableAddons(AddonLoader.java:309)
    at net.labymod.main.LabyMod.init(LabyMod.java:256)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:211)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:189)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:118)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.initializeMods(Loader.java:737)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.finishMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:310)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:495)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:329)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182)
    ... 46 more
```

How can I make my jar find the missing dependencies?

Comment: You can't just put jar files inside another jar and have it work out of the box. You either have to shade them (create "fat" or "über" jar) or have them next to your application and configure the classpath when starting it. For the former, check out the [shadow plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) for Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put the dependency jars into the main jar. You need to shade the dependencies into them.